# Android: how to Change row color based on specific condition?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a listview implemented whenever my application is opened up, my idea is to change each row color based on a condition, which are the following, this is not actual code, just pseudocode to show my idea:

```
 if condition = completed (row color is green)
 if condition = in Progress (row color is blue)
 if condition = pending (row color is red)
```

How would I implement this in my main activity class? please help!

Comment: Can u please add some more code to know how can u get, it's completed or not.?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when you create custom `ListView` items you have to create own implementation of `ListAdapter` for example extending `BaseAdapter` class. Inside adapter you will have items data where you bind it with created views.

View should be created with customized XML layout which contains element that changes color e.g. row background.

Your adapter `getView()` method which bind items data to view could look like this.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView textView;
    if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
        textView= new TextView(mContext);
        textView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
        textView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
    } else {
        textView= (TextView) convertView;
    }

    textView.setBackgroundColor(blue);
    return textView;
}
```

That's the basic idea. If you provide code that you have tried already I would be able to support you further.

Answer (score 0):

In order to process and test each entry you would need a custom adapter of some kind.
Here is a great tutorial on custom array adapters that I used.  You could test and modify the text color within the loop in the adapter.

[Custom Array Adapter Tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter)